# Prose Statement of Formulas

Tags: formatting

How can I write a prose statement for a particular formula. In other words, I would like to write

CV = the standard deviation/mean x 100

so that "standard deviation/mean" would appear like a fraction, with a horizontal division line and mean appearing under the standard deviation.

Answer (score 4):

This is your first question and first day at the site. Hence I will deploy crystal ball. This is how it is done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    %% provides \text{} macro and many more
\begin{document}
\[
\text{CV} = \frac{\text{the standard deviation}}{\text{mean} \times 100}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    %% provides \tex{} macro and many more
\begin{document}
\[
\text{CV} =\frac{\text{the standard deviation}}{\text{mean}} \times 100
\]
\[
\text{CV} = \biggl(\frac{\text{the standard deviation}}{\text{mean}}\biggr) 100
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I get the feeling I broke some rules of etiquette. I kept the question short so it was to the point. I'm sorry if it sounded brusque. But this formula isn't correct. It's the sum of the standard deviation divided by the mean that is multiplied by 100, not just the mean. So the formula is "(the standard deviation/mean) * 100" or. The CV is calculated by dividing the standard deviation by the mean, then multiplying by 100.

Comment: >Working from your example, I figured it out. It should be             >$\frac{\text{the standard deviation}}{\text{mean}}$$ \times 100$\br

Comment: Sorry, editing timed out before I could figure out how to do the correct formatting. (I accidentally posted rather than create a line break). The only problem is that font is pretty small, but I guess I can live with that.

Comment: @Joe I updated the formula.

Comment: I've seen `\mbox{}` used instead of `\text{}` for this job, could you explain the merits of `\text{}` over `\mbox{}`?

Comment: (Also, fwiw, it may be easier to use `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}` instead of `\bigll(...\bigrr)`, since it will autosize it for you!)

Comment: The difference is that `\text` resizes the contents according to the mathematical meaning. That is `$e^{\text{small}}$` makes superscript size text, while `$e^{\mbox{not so small}}$` makes text that is the size of the surrounding text font.